# How to convert a single column containing JSON with 250 variables to 250 separate column dataset using arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, json, large-files

I have an issue converting a JSON column (which contains around 250 variables) into 250 separate columns. I'm able to use Pandas dataframe, but just for 46k rows it takes 30 minutes and sometimes kernel is crashing due to low memory (for 0.5 million rows in database).

Can somebody help me with code using NumPy arrays (which should decrease conversion time and reduce file size)?

The JSON column has data in below format:

[image]

My code :

```
for x in records:
    list_ = list(x)
    json_acceptable_string = list_[4].read()
    list_features.append(json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
```

Once I get the list-features I'm preprocessing and using machine learning pipeline. This isn't working for large data.

Comment: Pandas is using numpy in the background already. Can you show us your code so far? If it's just too big to handle in RAM, have you tried Dask?

Comment: Have you tried `pandas.read_json`?

Comment: why you use a dictionary instead of a list?


`list_features.append([v for v in json.loads(json_acceptable_string).values()])`

Comment: @Niki.. issue is every row for that json column won't have all variables. some rows have 100 variables, some have all 250 variables.

Comment: @Naseer ok then variable names are the same for all the rows?

Comment: yes.. it just that variable with missing values won't be present in that json.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help for building your np array

```
variable_name_list = ['var1','va2',....,'var250']
list_features = np.empty(shape=(len(records),len(variable_name_list)),dtype=str)
for index in range(records):
    list_ = list(records[index])
    json_acceptable_string = list_[4].read()
    tmp_feature_list = []
    tmp_feature_dict = json.loads(json_acceptable_string)
    for var_name in variable_name_list:
        if var_name not in tmp_feature_dict.keys():
            tmp_feature_list.append("missing_val")
        else :
            tmp_feature_list.append(tmp_feature_dict[var_name])
    tmp_feature_list = np.asarray(tmp_feature_list,dtype=str).reshape(1,len(variable_name_list))
    list_features[index] = tmp_feature_list
```